# How can I know if there are innodb tables in a mysql server?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, innodb

I have a mysql server and I want to disable innodb support for it.

It's said that I can cut-off my memory usage up to 100MB.

I'm pretty sure but not 100% sure, that there is no innodb tables in the server.

Is there a *easy* way to be 100% sure that there is no innodb tables in the server so I can disable innodb support safely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the information_schema database:

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLES` WHERE `ENGINE` LIKE 'InnoDB'
```

That'll tell you which database and tables.

Answer (score 2):

```
select table_schema, table_name from
information_schema.tables where engine='innodb';
```